# Wait for web page to adjust DOM when viewport is changed in cypress

Tags: javascript, css, dom, cypress, responsive

I'm trying to change the viewport of my application multiple times using cypress.

```js
cy.viewport(393, 851);
// do something
cy.viewport(1366, 768);
// do something
```

Once the view port changes, the dom will take some time to adjust itself.

**How can I wait here for the dom to adjust itself and continue the execution?**

I have tried to reload the app after changing the view port. But I don't recommend this solution as it consumes time and not all pages are reloadable.

```js
cy.viewport(393, 851);
cy.reload();
// do something
cy.viewport(1366, 768);
cy.reload();
// do something
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to change the viewport in a test rather than launching the browser with desired viewport(s)?

Comment: @jjhelguero Yes, I'm using percy for visual regression - https://docs.percy.io/docs/debugging-sdks#responsive-dom-changes

I need to change the viewport multiple times to take snapshots at different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

A different way of changing viewports is by setting them via [test configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport#Set-viewport-in-the-test-configuration).

```js
describe(
  'page display on medium size screen',
  {
    viewportHeight: 1000,
    viewportWidth: 400,
  }
```

or

```js
it(
  'page display on medium size screen',
  {
    viewportHeight: 1000,
    viewportWidth: 400,
  }, () => {
  // visit and take snapshot
})
```